# WSO2 Identity Server not taking NameIDPolicy format into consideration for authentication request

Tags: wso2, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

We are sending following message while sending authentication request to WSO2 IS.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml2p:AuthnRequest AssertionConsumerServiceURL="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" Destination="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" ForceAuthn="false" 
ID="a2d12hcb8gd51i7923ba4976hh894a4" IsPassive="false" IssueInstant="2015-03-04T04:41:06.937Z" 
ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">anshul1</saml2:Issuer>
<saml2p:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress"/>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```

But no matter what we send in NameIdPolicy Format attribute, its not taking it into consideration while sending response.

Comment: Could you add more details in your question? How do you check, that "its not taking it into consideration while sending response"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. According the WSO2OIS source code,  it seems to be that, WSO2IS read the `NameIdPolicy` from the issuer configuration only.  It does not check for the SAML2 Auth Request. WSO2IS would return whatever that you have configured for `NameID format` in the SAML2 SSO issuer configurations.  You can refer latest code of from [here](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity/blob/master/components/sso-saml/org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/sso/saml/processors/SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor.java).  Just check on `populateServiceProviderConfigs()` method.  Hope it would fix in future.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that is the case only. Now we are using OpenAM for testing and it is working fine.